# What is the meaning of 'in articles' in following sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

> Precious stones formed an important item of trade **in articles** which were eagerly sought for by the Romans in the early centuries of the Christian era.

What is the meaning of 'in articles' in the above sentence?

Comment: Articles = things. Other peoples were trading with the Romans in things which included precious stones.

Comment: @KateBunting It means lot of items were traded, but stones is very important, am i right

Comment: Precious stones _were_ very important - yes.